# How to convert 32 bit RGBA image to 8 bit greyscale image in Java Android?

Tags: java, android, image-conversion

I wanted to convert 32 bit RGBA image to 8 bit greyscale image in Java Android.All other codes I tried converts RGBA (4 channel) to greyscale (4 channel).

Can anyone help or tell me on how to convert  RGBA (4 channel) image to greyscale (1 channel) image.

Comment: It would be great, if you could post some code of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please add some references or something you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the A-channel of your RGBA image will be ignored, when converting to 8-bit grayscale. At this point you will loose the informations of the alpha channel.

Converting a RGB image into grayscale can be done in serveral ways. The simplest approach is to simply take just one of the 3 channels (each channel has already 8-bit) and create a 8-bit image from this channel. You will see significant differences between the resulting grayscale images. Your conclusion might be, that it is no good idea to neglect 2 channels.

This might lead to the idea that the grayscale information of each pixel has to be dependent on all 3 channels (R, G and B).

On approach is to calculate the grayscale value as the average of R, G and B:

```
grayscale = (R+G+B)/3
```

A better way is to calculate it as the weighted sum:

```
grayscale = 0.21*R + 0.72*G + 0.07*B
```

Try this out and take a look at the results and the differences between them.